# How to make enemy meter detector in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx, transition, detect

In my top down game, I have an enemy detector to detect the enemy is near.My problem is how can I create animate my meter bar with transition? I'm to new to this framework. Thank's and Advance

When player detect the enemy near, the meter bar will animate just like the image screen shot bellow

[image: When enemy is near the player]

Without enemy

[image: Without enemy]
   [image]

**My code:**

```
    //detector
    meter_bar = new Texture("meter_bar.png");
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(meter_bar);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    actormeter_bar = new Image(myTexRegionDrawable);
    actormeter_bar.setPosition(200,1005);
    stage.addActor(actormeter_bar);

    meter = new Texture("meter.png");
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(meter);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    actormetter = new Image(myTexRegionDrawable);
    actormetter.setPosition(190,990);
    stage.addActor( actormetter);
```

**Player Movement (forward):**

```
//right_control
    right_paw = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("right_paw.png"));
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(right_paw);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    moveForward = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    moveForward.getStyle().imageUp = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("right_paw.png"))));
    //the hover
    moveForward.getStyle().imageDown = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("right_paw-hover.png"))));
    moveForward.setPosition(520,110);
    stage.addActor(moveForward); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    moveForward.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("Right Button Pressed");
            progressKnobX = progressKnobX + 4;

            actorprogressknob.setX(progressKnobX); // x-position to move to
            if(progressKnobX > 418 ) progressKnobX= 418 ;
            music.play();
            motionState=MotionState.NONE;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            motionState=MotionState.UP;
            return true;
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(moveForward);
```

**EnemySprite Movement:**

```
 zombie = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("enemy/ZombieSprite.png"));
    zombiesprite = new Sprite(zombie);
    zombieenemy = new Rectangle();
    zombieenemy.setWidth(zombiesprite.getWidth());

    zombieenemy = zombiesprite.getBoundingRectangle();
    zombieenemy.x = zombieX;
    zombieenemy.y = zombieY;
    TextureRegion[][] zom = TextureRegion.split(zombie, zombie.getWidth() / Zombie_FRAME_COLS, zombie.getHeight() / Zombie_FRAME_ROWS);
    TextureRegion[] zwalkFrames  = new TextureRegion[Zombie_FRAME_COLS * Zombie_FRAME_ROWS];
    index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Zombie_FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Zombie_FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            zwalkFrames[index++] = zom[i][j];
        }
    }
    zombiewalkAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.120f, zwalkFrames);
```

**MoveForward Button Function:**

```
//button functions
MotionState motionState=MotionState.NONE;
enum MotionState {
    NONE {
        @Override
        public boolean update(Rectangle player) {
            return true;
        }
    },
    UP {
        @Override
        public boolean update(Rectangle player) {
            player.y += 300 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            return false;
        }
    },
    DOWN{
        @Override
        public boolean update(Rectangle player) {
            player.y -= 300 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            return false;
        }
    },
    LEFT{
        @Override
        public boolean update(Rectangle player)  {
            player.x -= 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            return false;
        }
    },
    RIGHT{
        @Override
        public boolean update(Rectangle player) {
            player.x  += 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            return false;
        }
    };
    public abstract boolean update(Rectangle player);
}
```

Render

```
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)) motionState = MotionState.DOWN;
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) motionState=MotionState.UP;
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) motionState=MotionState.LEFT;
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) motionState=MotionState.RIGHT;

    if(motionState.update(player)) motionState=MotionState.NONE;


    if(player.y> 1910){
        zombieenemy.y -= 60 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Before I answer your initial question I'd like to suggest you learn to use [Libgdx extension Ashley](https://github.com/libgdx/ashley/wiki/How-to-use-Ashley) because the way things look like is very messy and will be hard for you to maintain.

**My Answer:**

hold an **ArrayList<>** or similar data model with all your game enemies inside, then we will iterate through each one and get it's position and calculate distance to the player.

```
Enemy closestEnemy = null;
float closestEnemyDist = -1;

for(Enemy enemy : ListOfEnemies){
    /* here we find the distance to the player */
    float distToPlayer = Math.sqrt((enemy.y-player.x)^2 + (enemy.y-player.y)^2);

    /* initiate closestEnemyDist for the first time */
    if(closestEnemyDist == -1){
         closestEnemyDist = distToPlayer;
    }

    /* we find the closest distance to the player */
    float minDist = Math.min(closestEnemyDist, distToPlayer);

    /* we make sure it is the closest and save the closest enemy as well */
    if(minDist <= closestEnemyDist){
        closestEnemyDist = minDist;
        closestEnemy = enemy;
    }
}
```

This gives you the closest Enemy and it's distance, you can make a method of it or get just the distance if you'd like, you can run this code every game update.

**The Distance Meter:**

here we gonna do a small math, let's say your meter shows percentages... from 0% to 100%, you must choose the maximum distance your meter considers 0% (meaning the enemy is very far call it maxDistance), for you to easily understand this imagine that distance is 100 and look at this method.

```
public int calcMeter(float closestEnemyDist, float maxDistance) {
    int meter = 0;

    /* calculate only if enemy is in range */
    if(closestEnemyDist < maxDistance){
        /* using rounding and multiply by 100f because we wanted 
         * values from 0 - 100, you can can modify this to work just 
         * with float from 0 - 1f 
         */
        meter = Math.round(
            /* 
             * here we flip the percentage so if the enemy is very
             * close then your meter will be higher 
             */
            (1f - (closestEnemyDist / maxDistance)) * 100f
        );
    }
    return meter;
}
```

Hope this helps you, Good Luck :)

Comment: Thank you Sir @Ariel Yust, I wil try your code and the libgdx ashley api

Comment: @jaZzZ, Glad to help you! if this solves your problem please mark it as the Answer, and keep us posted when you succeed :)

Answer (score 0):

I use the Stack class to create the Meter class. The meter image needs to be transparent and the bar image needs to be an animation. Stack Actor can overlap the images and render it on top of each other. Here is the Meter class:

```
public class Meter extends Stack {

    private Animation<Drawable> animation;
    private Image bar;

    public Meter( Skin skin ){

        Array<Drawable> drawables = new Array<Drawable>();

        for ( int i = 0; i < TestScreen.LENGTH; ++i ){
            drawables.add( skin.getDrawable( TestScreen.BAR + Integer.toString( i ) ) );
        }

        animation = new Animation<Drawable>( 1f, drawables );
        bar = new Image( animation.getKeyFrame( 0f ) );
        addActor( bar );
        addActor( new Image( skin.getDrawable( TestScreen.METER ) ) );
        setTouchable( Touchable.disabled );
    }

    /**
     * Set the "hotness" of the meter.
     * @param value float between 0 and 1
     */
    public void setValue( float value ){

        // actions are the default way to animate simple effects to the actors
        // this is just to add a pop in effect when you have a really smooth animation this isn't really necessary
        bar.addAction( Actions.sequence(
            Actions.alpha( 0 ),
            Actions.fadeIn( 0.01f, Interpolation.smooth )
        ) );

        // set the new image to the value percentage
        bar.setDrawable( animation.getKeyFrame( value * animation.getAnimationDuration() ) );
        bar.setSize( bar.getPrefWidth(), bar.getPrefHeight() );
    }
}
```

Stage class that uses skin to set the actors.

```
public class MyStage extends Stage {

    public Meter meter;

    public MyStage( Skin skin ){

        super();

        meter = new Meter( skin );

        Table table = new Table( skin );
        table.setFillParent( true );
        table.setOrigin( Align.top );
        table.add( meter ).width( (1/10f) * Gdx.graphics.getWidth() );

        addActor( table );
    }
}
```

Best practice is to create a skin and put all the ui resources in there. Load from file in a TextureAtlas object and pass that object into the skin. I created a simple animation this doesn't scale correctly its just as an example. In the screen object or game object:

```
private MyStage myStage;

@Override
public void show(){

    Skin skin = new Skin();
    skin.add( METER, new TextureRegionDrawable( new TextureRegion( meter_texture ) ), Drawable.class );

    float w = meter_bar_texture.getWidth() / (float) LENGTH;

    for ( int i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i ){
        TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion( meter_bar_texture, 0, 0, (int)(i * w), meter_bar_texture.getHeight() );

        skin.add( BAR + Integer.toString( i ), new TextureRegionDrawable( region ), Drawable.class );
    }

    this.myStage = new MyStage( skin );
}

@Override
public void hide() {

    super.hide();

    this.meter_bar_texture.dispose();
    this.meter_texture.dispose();
}

@Override
public void update( float delta ) {

    if ( dangerIncreased() && value < 100 ){
        danger += 5;

        this.myStage.meter.setValue( danger / 100f );
    } else if ( dangerDecreased() && danger > 0 ){
        danger -= 5;

        this.myStage.meter.setValue( danger / 100f );
    }

    this.myStage.act( delta );
}

public static final String METER = "meter";
public static final String BAR = "bar";
public static final int LENGTH = 10;
```